# Problem with too many sections and subsections

Tags: table-of-contents, sectioning, memory

I have been trawling this website for several days but found nothing close to my problem. The only questions that came close, I think, were dealing with inserts and memory requirements. I have cut down the sample code to the bare minimum. It was really hard to reproduce the problem but I think this codes does that. I am using PdfLaTeX with TeXShop on a new MacBook Pro with 32GB of RAM running Mojave.

The problem is that when I request a `tocdepth` of 3 the definition of `\ChapterN` appears to be lost because I get the error message:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> Chapter \@ChapterN 
                              \ - Blablabla
l.40 ...bsection}{\numberline {1.5.1}Blablabla}{4}
```

even though it *is* defined. If `tocdepth` is 2 the problem disappears. Crucially, if I specify `tocdepth` = 3 but delete one of the `\section`s or `\subsection`s, the problem disappears. This is why the minimum example below has so many `\section`s etc.

It looks like a memory issue to me, and I have a vague idea that increasing the argument of `\reserveinserts` might help, but I would rather get a proper diagnosis and some proper guidance instead of hacking randomly.

BTW, if you run this code the formatting will be kind of messed up but you can ignore that, it's just because I stripped the code down to reproduce just the problem at hand.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage{etex}
\reserveinserts{28}

\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\newtcbox{\mybox}{blank, on line, opacitytext=0.6}
\makeatletter
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\newcommand\ChapterN[1]{\def\@ChapterN{#1}}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\fancypagestyle{plain}{
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[L]{Left}
\fancyhead[C]{Centre}
\fancyhead[R]{Right}
\fancyfoot[L]{
    \setlength{\fboxsep}{2mm}
    \setlength{\fboxrule}{0.2mm}
    \fbox{\parbox{14.8cm}
    {\strut \mybox{\textcolor{red}
        {\textbf{Chapter \@ChapterN \ - Blablabla}}}}}}
\fancyfoot[C]{}
\fancyfoot[R]{
    \setlength{\fboxsep}{2mm}
    \setlength{\fboxrule}{0.2mm}
    \fbox{\parbox{1.35cm}{\strut\centering\thepage}}}}
\makeatother
\pagestyle{plain}
\usepackage{varwidth}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\ChapterN{A}
\chapter{Blablabla}
\section{Blablabla}
\subsection{Blablabla}
\subsubsection{IBlabla Blabla Blabla Blabla Blabla}
\subsubsection{Isdfgsdfgsdfg Blabla Blabla Blabla}
\subsection{klsdfhkajhfdg}
\subsection{Blabla Blabla Blabla Blabla Blabla}
\subsection{Blabla}
\subsection{Blabla Blabla Blabla Blabla}
\subsubsection{Blabla}
\subsubsection{Blabla}
\subsubsection{Blabla}
\subsubsection{Blabla}
\subsection{Blablabla}
\subsection{Blablabla}
\subsection{Blablabla}

\section{Blablabla Blablabla}
\subsection{Blablabla}
\subsection{Blablabla}
\subsubsection{Blablabla}
\subsubsection{Blablabla}
\subsubsection{Blablabla}
\subsubsection{Blablabla}
\subsubsection{Blablabla Blablabla}
\subsection{Blablabla Blablabla Blablabla}

\section{Blablabla}
\subsection{Blablabla}
\subsection{Blablabla}
\subsection{Blablabla}
\subsection{Blablabla}
\subsection{Blablablai}

\section{Blablabla}
\subsection{Blablabla}
\subsection{Blablabla}
\subsection{Blablabla}
\subsection{Blablabla}
\subsection{Blablabla}
\subsection{Blablabla Blablabla}

\section{Blablabla Blablabla Blablabla}
\subsection{Blablabla}
\subsection{Blablabla}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I can't test now but if I see it right the problem is that `\@ChapterN` is executed on the first page when you issue `\tableofcontents` and at that point it is still undefined.

Comment: Thanks @campa but I am not sure what you are saying is right. I added `\newcommand\ChapterN[1]{\def\@ChapterN{#1}}` after `\begin{document}` and before `\tableofcontents`, and got `! LaTeX Error: Command \ChapterN already defined.` I tried also with `\renewcommand` and in that case I got the old error.

Comment: I'm pretty sure I'm right `:-)` With `\secnumdetph=2` the table of contents is short, and the first use of `\ChapterN` is reached before the page is complete. Using the value 3 the table of contents is longer than one page, and when the first page is shipped out and the pagefoot is built, `\ChapterN` hasn't been issued yet and `\@ChapterN` is still undefined. Of course adding a new definition of `\ChapterN` after `\begin{document}` raises an error. You should add e.g. `\newcommand{\@ChapterN}{\relax}` in the preamble after the definition of `\ChapterN`.

Comment: It worked! :). In fact, I do remember reading about this a few months ago. Makes sense. Thank you very much

Comment: @epR8GaYuh, may I ask what you edited? I just want to know if I had made any errors in style or whatever.

Comment: Besides removing the "Thank you" (which is discouraged), I mostly tried to improve readability by adding some additional paragraphs. You can examine the changes yourself by opening the diff of my change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use the contents of `\ChapterN` in left-hand side footers of your document by passing it down via `\@ChapterN` to `\fancyfoot[L]` (headers and footers together are referred to as "pagestyle").

When the table of contents is rendered, it usually starts at an odd page (right hand side). If it is short enough, the left hand side will not be rendered at all, so no call to `\@ChapterN` is made. However, if the ToC is longer, it will eventually break to the next, left-hand, side, and the footer for that page is rendered, where you tell the fancyhdr package to utilize `\@ChapterN`. The problem is, that at that point that macro is still undefined, since your `\ChapterN` is after the `\tableofcontents`.

There are several ways to fix this: You could initialize `\@ChapterN` by calling `\ChapterN` immediately after it is defined:

```
\newcommand\ChapterN[1]{\def\@ChapterN{#1}}
\ChapterN{}
```

Now, `\@ChapterN` is empty, but defined, so when the ToC is broken onto the next page, the pagestyle can call `\@ChapterN`. Note that then you will get "Chapter - Blablabla" as footer on the second contents page, and you problably don't want that.

Alternatively, you can tell `fancyhdr` to only use `\@ChapterN`  if it has been initialized:

```
\fancyfoot[L]{
  \ifx\@ChapterN\@undefined\else
    \setlength{\fboxsep}{2mm}
    \setlength{\fboxrule}{0.2mm}
    \fbox{\parbox{14.8cm}
    {\strut \mybox{\textcolor{red}
        {\textbf{Chapter \@ChapterN \ - Blablabla}}}}}
  \fi
  }
```

Now you are telling the package to render the left-hand side footer only if `\@ChapterN` is defined. Otherwise the footer on left-hand pages is left completely empty.

The cleanest way, however, would be to use (or define) different page styles for toc and text, respectively:

```
...
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}% no headers/footers for ToC
\tableofcontents
\ChapterN{A}
\pagestyle{plain}% re-activate page styles
...
```

Comment: Thank you very much @Lupino, very comprehensive and clear answer.